# Haskell STM : How to store ThreadID as per their execution sequence

Tags: haskell, stm

In the following program Fibonacci number is generated from a given integer (generated randomly) and that value is stored into a TVar. As the execution time for generating the Fibonacci is different for different number, thus threads will not run sequentially. **I want to store theadID, may be in a list, to check their execution pattern.**
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
module Main
where
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent
import System.Random 
import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef
import System.IO

nfib :: Int -> Int
nfib n | n <= 2 = 1
   | otherwise = par n1 (pseq n2 (n1 + n2 ))
                 where n1 = nfib (n-1)
                       n2 = nfib (n-2)


type TInt = TVar Int


updateNum :: TInt -> Int -> STM()
updateNum n v = do x1 <- readTVar n
                   let y = nfib v
                   x2 <- readTVar n
                   if x1 == x2
                   then writeTVar n y   
                   else retry

updateTransaction :: TInt -> Int -> IO ()
updateTransaction n v = do atomically $ updateNum n v

incR :: IORef Int -> Int -> IO ()
incR r x = do { v <- readIORef r;                    
      writeIORef r (v - x) }

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    n <- newTVarIO 10
    r <- newIORef 40;
    forM_ [1..10] (\i -> do 
                     incR r i
                     ;v <- readIORef r
                     ;forkIO (updateTransaction n v)
                    )
```

I want to store [TreadID,FibNo] into a List for all the threads as per their execution. Suppose T1 has executed Fib30, T2 Fib35, T3->32 and T4->40. And if the commit sequence of threads like T1,T3, T2 and T4 then I want to store T1-35,T3-32,t2-35,t4-40 in a list.

**Edit:**
As suggested by @MathematicalOrchid, I have modified updateTrasaction as follows:-

```
updateTransaction :: MVar [(ThreadId, Int)] -> TInt -> Int -> IO ()
updateTransaction mvar n v = do
  tid <- myThreadId
  atomically $ updateNum n v
  list <- takeMVar mvar
  putMVar mvar $ list ++ [(tid, v)]
```

Now I am trying to print the values from that list in main

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  ...
  ...
  m <- newEmptyMVar
  ...
  ...
  mv <- readMVar m
  putStrLn ("ThreadId, FibVal : "  ++ " = " ++ (show mv))
```

At the time of execution. MVar values couldn't be read and generates error

```
Exception: thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation
```

What to do? Thank in advance.

Comment: You are aware that your Fibonacci implementation is _really_ slow? Or do you want to use that function as a test?

Comment: Fibonacci function as a test. For e.g. as Fibonacci 35 will take more time than Fibonacci 25 and thus execution time for the thread1 (Fib 35) will take more time than thread 2 (Fib 25). Thus tread2 will execute first and then thead1 (because of 'retry').

Comment: `x1 <- readTVar n; …; x2 <- readTVar n`? You are aware that this is completely not necessary?

Comment: What makes you think that `else` branch will ever execute? If `x1 /= x2` then GHC will automatically abort the transaction.

Comment: @Zeta, please help me to clear my doubts. I have stored the value of n into x1, at first, and then into x2. I did so to check the data inconsistency so, on the basis of that  to write into TVar or to retry. Can Haskell STM be able to retry automatically in chase of data inconsistency. As I know in this case it should abort.

Comment: @AmmlanGhosh: You've read http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch10.html, right? *"When an STM computation is performed like this, it is called a transaction because the whole operation takes place atomically with respect to the rest of the program."* Inside of an transaction no `TVar` can change its value, except if that change has happened _inside_ that transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you want something like

```
updateTransaction :: TInt -> Int -> IO ()
updateTransaction n v = do
  tid <- myThreadId
  putStrLn $ "Start " ++ show tid
  atomically $ updateNum n v
  putStrLn $ "End " ++ show tid
```

Or perhaps something like

```
updateTransaction :: TInt -> Int -> IO ThreadId
updateTransaction n v = do
  atomically $ updateNum n v
  myThreadId
```

and change `forM_` to `forM`?

---

Also, this part:

```
do
  x1 <- readTVar n
  ...
  x2 <- readTVar n
  if x1 == x2 ...
```

If `x1 /= x2` then GHC will *automatically* abort and restart your transaction. You do not need to manually check this yourself. Indeed, the else-branch can *never* execute. That's kind of the *point* of STM; it will appear to your transaction that nobody else changes the data you're looking at, so you don't ever have to worry about concurrent writes.

---

**Edit:** If you want to record the actual order in which the transactions committed, you're going to need some more inter-thread communication. Obviously you could do that with STM, but just for a list of stuff, maybe this could work?

```
updateTransaction :: MVar [(ThreadId, Int)] -> TInt -> Int -> IO ()
updateTransaction mvar n v = do
  tid <- myThreadId
  fib <- atomically $ updateNum n v
  list <- takeMVar mvar
  putMVar mvar $ list ++ [(tid, fib)]
```

(Obviously you have to make `updateNum` return the number it calculated.)

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. You are correctly said that x1 /= x2 will abort the transaction. A transaction may execute or may abort and restart again. I want to store [TreadID,FibNo] into a List for all the threads as per their execution. Suppose T1 has executed Fib30, T2 Fib35, T3->32 and T4->40. And if the commit sequence of threads like T1,T3, T2 and T4 then I want to store T1-35,T3-32,t2-35,t4-40 in a list.

Comment: Thank you @MathematicalOrchid. Let me try.

Comment: Thank @MathematicalOrchid. As per your advice I have modified upateTransaction. [i.e. `updateTransaction :: MVar [(ThreadId, Int)] -> TInt -> Int -> IO ()  ... .... putMVar mvar $ list ++ [(tid, v)]` (I want to store v instead of fib, thus modified accordingly).  In main, I have declare `m <- newEmptyMVar` and called `forkIO (updateTransaction m n v)`. But I couldn't able to print the values of `m` in the main. Please help.

Comment: To clarify: You can't work out what to write? Or you wrote something and it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: To: @MathematicalOrchid; I have edited my question and added the code for your kind perusal.

Comment: You created an _empty_ `MVar`. You need to create one that starts off containing `[]`.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I have corrected my code as `m <- newEmptyMVar  putMVar m []`